# Scraping selenium with html template

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, dictionary, web-scraping

I made an html template that I want to fill with content extracted from a web with python - selenium

```
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import csv 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))


driver.get('https://es.hoteles.com/ho227810/secrets-lanzarote-resort-spa-adults-only-18-yaiza-espana/')

time.sleep(3)

try:
    cookies = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'osano-cm-button--type_accept')
    cookies.click()
    time.sleep(2)
except:
    pass


try:
    tamano_hotel = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section#Amenities div.uitk-layout-columns-item')
    hotel=[]
    dictdetails={}
    for iterarhotel in tamano_hotel:
        dictdetails[iterarhotel.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h3").text]=",".join([item.text for item in iterarhotel.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//ul//li")])
        hotel.append(dictdetails)
    print(hotel[1])
    time.sleep(2)        
except:
    print("Nothing")
```

I have extracted a dictionary, but I don't know why it extracts the same content several times and only the first h3.

Would it be possible to extract the content and put it automatically in the html template?
The template would be a table and the content would have to go in the second  the h3 and in the fourth  the items separated by ,

Example:

```
 <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-check red-color"></i></td>
            <td>Hotel size</td>.
            <td><i class="fa fa-arrow-right red-color"></i></td>
             <td>331 rooms, 8 floors</td>.
</tr>
```

url: https://es.hoteles.com/ho227810/secrets-lanzarote-resort-spa-adults-only-18-yaiza-espana/

img: [image]

Comment: Please provide the step to get the hotel size. I can't find hotel size the link you have given. Also provide your data structure how you wanted to display.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood. The size of the hotel is a h3 inside "At a glance".

I add to the question an image to clarify it, color: yellow are h3, color: blue the items  thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you are printing this `print(hotel[1])` , you should print this `print(hotel)`

Answer (score 0):

This is dictionary list, to extract key and value from dictionary items you need to iterate the list and then dictionary items.

```
for h in hotel:
    for key, value in h.items():
        print("h3 tag text : " + key)
        print("li tag text : " + value)
```